# What does star in .sha file mean?

Tags: checksum

> The output contains one line per file of the form `"{hash} SPACE ASTERISK [{directory} SLASH] {filename}"`.

So what does `*` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `sha1sum(1)` man page:

> The default mode is
>          to print a line with checksum, a space, a  character  indicating  input
>          mode  ('*'  for binary, ' ' for text or where binary is insignificant),
>          and name for each FILE.

Therefore, it means that the file is binary when knowing that is significant.

Comment: So there is either ` *` or `  ` (2 spaces) between hash and filename? Is it the same for md5sum and other checksums?

Comment: What do their man pages say?

Comment: Why can it be important to know if it's binary or text file?

Comment: Not really sure, it's all the same here.

Comment: The significance is that Windows uses `CR/LF` as a new-line sequence, while Linux and OSX use `LF`. A text file would show different binary check-sums if transferred between Windows and Linux/OSX in Ascii mode, but identifying the file type as text makes sure that the check-sums are the same on each OS by taking account of the local new-line sequence.

Comment: @AFH does sha1sum & co calculate checksums differently in text/binary mode?

Comment: @SmitJohnth - I don't know specifically about `sha1sum`, but other software reads a `CR/LF` sequence on Windows as if it were a single `LF`, and I guess `sha1sum` does this for check-sum compatibility with non-Windows systems.